# Docker-Compose with Gitlab-CI managing sensitive data

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to create a ci/cd pipeline with gitlab. Currently I set my sensitive data as environment variables in the docker-compose file. I don't want this data to be visible in the repository.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: This was helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/gitlab/comments/afuwp9/how_do_i_pass_a_gitlab_ci_variable_into_a/

Answer (score 0):

You can add Variables to GitLab using the GitLab UI.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#masked-variables

See also https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/1452

Answer (score 0):

you should past your sensible data in the "ci cd" menu available in "settings". In your job, you can use them as a local variable.